# Clip Management won't work outside of ArcMap/Catalog

Tags: arcpy, error-999999, idle, pythonwin

Okay so I have a short script that works great when copied into the python window in ArcMap or ArcCatalog, but refuses to work in an IDE for whatever reason.  The error that is thrown is:

```
Start Time: Thu Oct 09 09:16:51 2014
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (Clip).
Failed at Thu Oct 09 09:16:51 2014 (Elapsed Time: 0.00 seconds)
```

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
import arcpy.sa

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\sadkins\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Watersheds\\lake\\outputs"
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = "C:\\Users\\sadkins\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Watersheds\\scratch"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = arcpy.SpatialReference(102685)
flowDir = "C:\\Users\\sadkins\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Watersheds\\inputs\\dir"
flowAcc = "C:\\Users\\sadkins\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Watersheds\\inputs\\acc"
lakeInput = "C:\\Users\\sadkins\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\lake\\lake1.shp"

try:
    tempAccClip = arcpy.Clip_management(flowAcc,"#","tempAcc",lakeInput,"0","ClippingGeometry")
    maxRas = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(tempAccClip,MAXIMUM)
    maxCell = arcpy.sa.EqualTo(tempAccClip,maxRas)
    pourPoint = arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(maxCell,"pourPoint.shp")
    outWatershed = arcpy.sa.Watershed(flowDir,pourPoint)
    outWatershed.save("lakeWatershed.shp")

except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Comment: What bit level of Python are you using?

Comment: I am using 32-bit; neither pythonwin or ILDE seem to want to run it.

Comment: Try setting from arcpy import env.

Comment: What happens when you just hardwire all the Clip parameters into a two line test script (with `import arcpy` as first line).  I would be keen to see the IDLE banner and error message, and the exact Python code, if this falls over.

Comment: PolyGeo:

Hardwiring the extents and file paths works, but I need to be flexible with the extents and parameters because I plan on doing this for a large number of polygon features (lakes) in a county.

Basically, I'm using this a test script before I throw a searchCursor and for loop in there.

Comment: When I see ERROR 999999 my first suspicion is always whether I have enough RAM available for what I am trying to do.  If you are in a position to try the same code and data with much more RAM to see if it "just works" then that may save you a lot of futile debugging.  If such a test is not easy then try using fewer, smaller datasets to as a test of your code logic.

Comment: If this is still an issue then I think you should remove those `try`/`except` statements (which may be masking errors), re-test and re-post any error messages.